# Can't rewrite block (Mage_Review_Block_Product_View) Magento M1

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, overrides

Cant rewrite `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View` for some reason.

In my config file I have:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_ModuleName>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </NameSpace_ModuleName>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <NameSpace_ModuleName before="Mage_Adminhtml">NameSpace_ModuleName_Adminhtml</NameSpace_ModuleName>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Review>
                    <file>namespace/review.xml</file>
                </Review>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <review>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <NameSpace_ModuleName before="Mage_Review">NameSpace_ModuleName</NameSpace_ModuleName> 
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </review>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Review>
                    <file>namespace/product-review-extended.xml</file>
                </Review>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Review>
                <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Helper</class>
            </Review>
        </helpers>  
        <blocks>
            <Review> 
                <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Block</class> 
            </Review>
            <review>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view>NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Product_View</product_view> 
                </rewrite>
            </review>            
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_edit_form>NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Review_Edit_Form</review_edit_form> 
                </rewrite>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_add_form>NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Review_Add_Form</review_add_form> 
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_pager>NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Page_Html_Pager</html_pager> 
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <review_resource>
                <rewrite>
                  <review>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_Review</review>
                </rewrite>
            </review_resource>
             <review_resource>
                <rewrite>  
                  <review_collection>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Resource_Review_Collection</review_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </review_resource>
            <Review>
                <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model</class>
            </Review>
        </models>
        <events>
            <review_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <NameSpace_ModuleName>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>notifyRecipient</method>
                    </NameSpace_ModuleName>
                </observers>
            </review_save_after>
        </events>
        <template>
            <email>
                <review_email_notification_optionamespace_email_template tranamespacelate="label" module="review">
                    <label>Product Review Notification</label>
                    <file>product_review_notification.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </review_email_notification_optionamespace_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

And I place file the following path: `Local/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Product/View.php`

with class name extended like this: `class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

But it would not extend it for some reason. Its not cache, and the rest of the module works fine.

Please help dont know what to try.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I guess your class should extend `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View`.

Comment: It doesn't even pointing at the View class file. The problem is somewhere in config.xml, I think it might be rewrite path that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<global>    
    <blocks>
        <review>
            <rewrite>              
                <product_view>NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Product_View</product_view> 
            </rewrite>
        </review> 
    </blocks>
<global>
```

> NameSpace/ModuleName/Block/Product/View.php

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: I got same thing, Tried it with Mage_Review_Block_Product_View as well. but its not pointing to rewrite class at all. Something wrong in config.xml i think.

Comment: You module is working correctly ? try to clean the cache

Comment: I did, removed cache directory.

Comment: What about your module ?

Comment: Works fine, I have multiple block classes rewrite all pooling and pointing fine.

Comment: Developed a lot of modules before but its first time i have trouble rewriting this particular block class.

Comment: I don't see the problem, can you share your `config.xml`

Comment: I posted entire config.xml content

Comment: Looking at your `config.xml`, I think calling your node `Review` can cause issue (as the native node is `review`). You should call your node with a specific name like `mymodulename_review`

Comment: Rechecked everything a 100 times spelling, file structure still nothing.

Comment: replace  all `<Review> ` with `<review> `

Comment: Yea thought so too but then rewritten this class in a different module with different node. Still same thing.

Comment: Gonna try to create brand new module. With just one block overwritten.

Comment: Still unable to do that. With brand new module with just one block class. it does not rewrite it.

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite this block for which file ?

Comment: I want to rewrite it cause its preparing collection(Review/Review). And would like to sort this collecting depending on what admin choses. Its for review/product/view/list.phtml file

Comment: Please go to `review/product/view/list.phtml` then give the result of this: `<?php var_dump(get_class($this))?>`

Comment: It outputs "Mage_Review_Block_Product_View" same class I was rewriting.

Comment: ok, it well the block that you're rewriting. I don't know why. the only thing I suspect is your cache

Comment: try to copy `app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View/List.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View/List.php` then put your changes

Comment: Can you please created module of your own and rewrite that single class. I did it on fresh clean installation with just one single block rewritten. And it just wont work. Idk what else to try, never had issues rewriting blocks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85042/discussion-on-answer-by-prince-cant-rewrite-block-mage-review-block-product-vi).